# Configure the port knocking server (knockd)?

Tags: raspbmc, iptables

I'm trying to configure [port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) on my RasPI running **Raspbmc**, using [knockd](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock/).

Here's what I've done:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install knockd
```

...then edited the files:

`/etc/default/knockd` :

```
# PLEASE EDIT /etc/knockd.conf BEFORE ENABLING
START_KNOCKD=1
```

`/etc/knockd.conf`:

```
[options]
        logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[open_close-PPTP_VPN]
        sequence      = 3141,5926,5359
        seq_timeout   = 10
        tcpflags      = syn,ack
        start_command = /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
        cmd_timeout   = 45
        stop_command  = /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
```

then start the daemon:

```
sudo service knockd restart
```

Check it's up:

```
ps aux |grep knoc
```

=>

```
root     12560  0.0  1.1   6028  4424 ?        Ss   02:55   0:00 /usr/sbin/knockd -d
pi       12877  0.0  0.1   1972   612 pts/1    S+   02:57   0:00 grep knoc
```

Capture packets to see what's happening on the wire.

```
sudo tcpdump 'src 211.212.77.33 and portrange 3000-6000 and tcp' -nn
```

Now test (from an Android Phone, using 3G data and app [Port Knocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smpaine.portknocker&hl=en)) - here's the output (192.168.1.31 is the IP of RasPi).

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
02:56:15.244087 IP 211.212.77.33.55399 > 192.168.1.31.3141: Flags [S], seq 3126604301, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,wscale 3], length 0
02:56:15.528594 IP 211.212.77.33.55405 > 192.168.1.31.5926: Flags [S], seq 2477232254, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,wscale 3], length 0
02:56:15.824344 IP 211.212.77.33.55408 > 192.168.1.31.5359: Flags [S], seq 154955077, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,wscale 3], length 0
```

Nice and dandy, 3 TCP packets, each about 300 ms apart, on the correct ports.

... but `watch iptables -L -n` shows no changes in the iptables config.

Also, there's nothing in the `knockd` log file except the 'server started message'.

It appears the knockd server either doesn't receive the packets, or fails to recognize them...

I even tried the 'start command' `touch /tmp/knock.txt` but of course, the file failed to make an appearance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cracked it.

TLDR: Use this line:

```
tcpflags      = syn
```

instead of this :

```
tcpflags      = syn,ack
```

Long story:

I found it useful when debugging to run the knockd daemon in interactive mode:

```
sudo service knockd stop
sudo knockd -D -v
```

This way the daemon runs in the foreground and prints its configuration and then real-time status messages.

I then tried port-knocking from the mobile phone. Packets got through (verified with `tcpdump`) but no response from `knockd`.

As suggested by @lenik in a comment, I editied `/etc/knockd.conf` and commented out the `tcpflags` line.

Insert another coin... (restart the knockd daemon...) and success! Status update messages started coming in!

Apparently, the config line:

```
tcpflags      = syn,ack
```

...means: "only look at packets that have BOTH the SYN and the ACK flags set"! which, while technically possible, is unlikely to happen.

In my tests, I found from the tcpdump output that the actual knock packets (with flag SYN) were shortly (1-2 sec) followed by an equal number of packets, using the same destination ports, but with the RST flag set - sometimes, but not always, in the same order.

This sometimes created duplicated entries in the iptables rules.

In the end, what worked for me was:

```
tcpflags      = syn
```

I assume the following would also work (didn't test):

```
tcpflags      = syn,!rst
```

Now if I could only figure out why Vodafone Romania is blocking the PPTP port on their 3G plan...

Answer (score 0):

```
start_command = sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
```

where the `sudo` password is coming from? since this command is supposed to be issued by daemon, you'd better replace it with (no `sudo`):

```
start_command = /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding `sudo`'s was a "call of last resort" (which didn't work either). I tried it because: 1. calling sudo from the command line manually has NEVER prompted me for a password on this machine so I thought there's something hard-wired in RaspBMC; 2. the "normal" way (without sudo)  didn't work and I thought the `knockd` daemon doesn't have enough privileges (I checked *afterwards* and `knockd` runs as `root`). I updated the question to remove the `sudo` calls, as they are misleading. Other suggestions? :D (Or ways to debug this?)

Comment: other suggestions? well, i'd replace `/sbin/iptables ...` with `echo blahblah >/home/user/blah.txt` to see if `start_command` is getting called. if no result, I'd increase timeouts to the outrageously large values. if still no result, I'd remove `tcp_flags`, or, instead, use some rare combination to ignore any other connection attempts while trying to knock things through. if still no result, i'd check `netstat -pl` to make sure the daemon is actually listening to the ports.

Comment: Already tried - look at the end of the question. The command I used is `touch /tmp/knock.txt`. No file was created there...

Comment: I'll check with `netstat` although I'm not sure the daemon is actively listening to anything. Not sure about the actual implementation of knockd (although I may get there if no other leads...) but [the Wikipedia article on port knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) suggests this about "usual implementations": (snip)

Comment: "This is usually implemented by configuring a daemon to watch the firewall log file for said connection attempts then modify the firewall configuration accordingly. It can also be performed by a process examining packets at a higher level (using packet capture interfaces such as pcap), allowing the use of already "open" TCP ports to be used within the knock sequence."

Comment: Another [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-iptables-knockd-port-knocking-tutorial/) suggests knockd listens for packets at OSI Layer 2: "This port need not be open -- since knockd listens at the link-layer level, it sees all traffic even if it's destined for a closed port"

Comment: If all else fails, I'll take a look at the similar (but apparently better) [Single Packet Authorization](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwknop/) technique.

Comment: Figured it out :) +1 for your comment that set me in the right direction!